# Is there a SwiftUI equivalent to WKInterfaceController's .becomeCurrentPage method?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

Previously in WatchKit we could tell a certain InterfaceController to present itself using [.becomeCurrentPage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619564-becomecurrentpage), how can we do it in Swift UI?

In WatchKit for example I would:

```
  // handle notification
    @objc func respondToWaterlock(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        self.becomeCurrentPage()
    }
```

Comment: can you provide some of your code?
what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani sure thing, added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no equivalent for [becomeCurrentPage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619564-becomecurrentpage) method in SwiftUI. You can update your [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) or ViewModel to achieve a similar result.
for example:

```
enum Pages {
    case home
    case settings
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    @State var selectedPage: Pages = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if self.selectedPage == .home {
                Text("Home")
            } else if self.selectedPage == .settings {
                Text("Settings")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

You should just update the `selectedPage` state variable to change the page.